# How to apply a macro to each column of a table

Tags: tables, macros

I want to apply a macro to all the cells of a column with the cell content as the input to the macro. Is this possible?

For example if the cell contents have the word TEST, the macro should take TEST as its argument.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
\def\mymacro#1{\lowercase{#1}}
\halign{&\mymacro{#}\cr
HELLO&WORLD\cr
TEST&123\cr}
\bye
```

For Yiannis's comment to apply the macro only to the first column, change the preamble (`&\mymacro{#}\cr`) to `\mymacro{#}&&#\hfil\cr`, for example. An ampersand at the very beginning tells TeX to repeat the definition(s) for every column, whereas `&&` defines that the following column definitions should be repeated.

Ofcourse, you don't *need* to repeat anything if you don't want to.

Comment: @morsburg I am not very familiar with TeX's tables, how would you apply the macro only on the first column?

Comment: @Yiannis: I've updated the answer to include a solution for your question. BTW, my handle is `morbusg`, not `morsburg`.

Comment: @morbusg: Very nice plainTeX solution! Thank you very much for explaining the things about repeating column definitions in the preamble. I didn't know about them yet.

Comment: @morbusg thanks for posting the additional comments. Sorry for the "burg", I spent too many years in South Africa!

Comment: @Martin: In my opinion, morbusg's answer shows that plain TeX tables are great! No need for any package. (No offense meant `:-)`) Can't you just do this in `collcell` somehow? @morbusg: +1, nicely written up answer!

Comment: @Hendrik: In theory it would be possible to extend `array` to not only have `>` and `<` to add material before and after the `#` in the internal `\halign` preamble, but actually insert full column description as one expression like `\mymacro{#}` above. However, it's not that simple to do.

Comment: @Martin: Perhaps one should just write a different version of the `array` package that _doesn't_ have `<` and `>`?

Comment: @Hendrik: `>` and `<` are fine, it just needs another character which allows to insert both sides of the code at the same time.

Comment: @Martin: Sorry, I didn't express myself clearly enough. What I meant: If you have `#`, then `>` and `<` are no longer needed. In fact, you're back to the plain TeX syntax, which I like best!

Comment: @Hendrik: I see, however there is no much reason to disallow the widely used `>`/`<` characters even if you have access to `#`.

Comment: @Martin: That's true. Unless it would simplify the implementation a lot.

Comment: @Hendrik: it is possible to do that using `>{...}` and gobbling the hash which represents the cell body in the preamble (see below). But in general @morbusg's approach (and my adaptation to LaTeX) forces the user to explictly write something (e.g. `\cr`, `\crcr`, `\\`) at the end of the last line  of the tabular if the last column is of the type that takes arguments.

Comment: @Bruno: Thanks for the comment! Somehow I think it was a bad idea of the LaTeX authors to _not_ have ``\\`` in the end of the last row. It's a hassle if you keep swapping rows ...

Comment: @morbusg: Will this work also for something like `\def\mymacro#1{\lowercase{#1}} \tabskip=0pt \halign to .5\hsize{ \vrule\tabskip=4pt#&\mymacro{#}\tabskip=0pt plus 1fil\strut&#\tabskip=4pt&\vrule#\cr &HELLO & WORLD&\cr &TEST & My number 123&\cr }`?

Comment: @Ahmed: do you mean repeating? Or applying the `\mymacro`? The `#`-symbol inside the preamble represents the stuff that gets inserted into the alignment, so if you mean applying the macro, then by changing the plain `#` by `\mymacro{#}` will change that column. If you meant repeating, then, well, I find it more productive to first just construct the preamble without repeats, and only if it's instantly apparent one could use repeats, to use them. I cannot instantly see how to repeat your example because of the `fil` and `vrule`s.

Comment: @morbusg: +1. What an elegant solution!

Answer (score 21):

You can use the relatively new [`collcell`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collcell) package to collect the cell content and feed it to a macro of your choice. It uses the `array` package to place code before and after each cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{array}% actually already loaded by `collcell`
\newcommand*{\mymacro}[1]{\fbox{#1}}% Do anything you like with `#1`
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\mymacro}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{CC}
  TestA  & A longer test cell \\
  \empty & The new version supports 'verb'! \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Make sure you use the version 2011/02/27 (or later) which contains a lot of improvements.

There is also the possibility to do it the following way, which compiles faster than `collcell` but does not work in the last cell of each row. It reads everything between the internally used macros `\ignorespaces` and `\unskip`.
I got this from [Ulrike Fischer on de.c.t.t](http://groups.google.com/group/de.comp.text.tex/tree/browse_frm/thread/5c43d35454662421/1881e16c28d234ea?rnum=1&_done=%2Fgroup%2Fde.comp.text.tex%2Fbrowse_frm%2Fthread%2F5c43d35454662421%3F#doc_f01e8d784b9b716d) a while ago.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand*{\mymacro}[1]{\fbox{#1}}

\def\simplecollect#1#2\ignorespaces#3\unskip{#1{#3}\unskip}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\simplecollect\mymacro}c}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{Sc}
  TestA  & Doesn't work in the last cell \\
  \empty & Sorry!  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution!

Comment: @Yiannis: Thanks. I needed this once for my `tikz-timing` package and then started to code `collcell`. Ironically, `tikz-timing` now simply removes `\ignorespaces` and uses `\unskip` or `\\ ` as end-marker, so it doesn't need `collcell` :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for `collcell`. Compared with `\ignorespaces…\unskip`, it has several advantages, including stripping off trailing whitespace (I wanted to use the content of the cell as a label) and not causing errors when encountering `\noalign` in a `tabularx` environment (that may not be the exact issue, I stopped debugging because collcell just works).

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using the `array` package and defining a `\newcolumntype`.

For example we can define a macro `\test` that can take a parameter as its argument and capitalize it.

```
\def\test#1 {\uppercase{#1}}
```

We can then define a new column type as:

```
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\test}l<{.}}
```

and our minimal example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
  \def\test#1 {\uppercase{#1}}
  \newcolumntype{D}{>{\test}l<{.}}
  \begin{tabular}{DD}
    test &test \\
    other &test \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Please note that this approach involves *delimited* macros, in this case the space after the word in the table acts to tell the command that it must only read up to there and obviously will fail if there are more than one word as Martin pointed out. One could use other types of delimiters perhaps a `.` or a `!`.

Comment: This doesn't work in the general case. Here `\test` reads everything to the first space as argument. So cells with more than a single word or such not ending in a space will fail.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** added support for `\multicolumn`.

This solution is more or less a LaTeX version of @morbusg's plain TeX answer. `\span` forces the expansion of the next token when TeX reads the preamble. `\@gobbletwo` removes the tokens forming the normal preamble which is inserted by `{tabular}`: this way, we move the `#` (i.e. body of the cell) to the middle of what `>{...}` inserts, rather than after it. More explanations after the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\def\KWP@safe@newline{%
  \iffalse{\fi
  \let\KWP@old@newline\\%
  \let\\\cr
  \iffalse}\fi
}
\def\KWP@restore@newline{\iffalse{\fi\let\\\KWP@old@newline\iffalse}\fi}

\newcolumntype{\arg}[1]{%
  >{\KWP@safe@newline
    #1{\ignorespaces \@sharp\unskip}%
    \KWP@restore@newline
    \span\@gobbletwo}%
  c}

\newcolumntype{\argmulti}[1]{%
  >{\KWP@safe@newline
    #1{\ignorespaces \@sharp\unskip}%
    \KWP@restore@newline
    \@gobbletwo}%
  c}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

First test.
\begin{tabular}{c\arg{\textbf}}
    abc & bcd \\
    cde & def \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{#1: $(#1)^{#1}$}%
Second test.
\begin{tabular}{|\arg{\mymacro}|c|}
    abc & bcd \\
    cdefgh & A\\
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ABC}\\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    abc & bcd \\
    cdefgh & A\\
    \multicolumn{2}{|\argmulti{\mymacro}|}{ABC}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

To give an idea of what's going on, let's look at the preamble constructed in the case of the column specification `\arg{\textbf}`. The "new" part is between `\KWP@safe@newline` and `\@gobbletwo` three lines below.

`\KWP@safe@newline` saves `\\`, and lets it to `\cr`. Otherwise, the macro, looking for an argument, would grab everything until the end of the cell, *without expanding*, and would not see the `\cr` hidden in the definition of `\\`. We'll restore the former definition with `\KWP@restore@newline`.

`\textbf{\ignorespaces \@sharp \unskip}` is just our macro. `\ignorespaces` and `\unskip` remove spaces from the argument (a better way would trim spaces expandably and pass the argument to `\textbf`), and `\@sharp` is let to `#`, which represents the body of the cell.

Finally, `\span\@gobbletwo` expands when the preamble is read (i.e., earlier than everything else here), and removes the `\@sharp` (and `\ignorespaces`, which I don't care about).

```
\@preamble ->\ialign \bgroup \unhcopy \@arstrutbox 
\hskip \col@sep \hfil 
\d@llarbegin 
\KWP@safe@newline 
\textbf {\ignorespaces \@sharp \unskip }%
\KWP@restore@newline 
\span \@gobbletwo \ignorespaces \@sharp \unskip \relax 
\d@llarend 
\hfil \hskip \col@sep 
\tabskip \z@ \cr
```

Caveat: if the last column specifier is that `\arg`, then the last line of the tabular *must* be terminated with `\\` (or `\cr` or `\crcr`).

Comment: @Bruno thanks! I don't understand much of the code, but it works nicely.

Comment: @Bruno: Great code! However I have difficulties to use this column type with `\multicolumn`.

Comment: @Martin: thanks. What exactly do you expect of e.g. `\begin{tabular}{\arg{\mymacro}c} a&b\\ \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{cde} \\ \end{tabular}`?

Comment: @Bruno: No I meant using `\arg` in the second argument of `\multicolumn` doesn't work.

Comment: @Martin: done. See my update. A matter of removing `\span` and adding some `\iffalse{\fi... \iffalse}\fi`.

Comment: @Martin: thinking again about it, what would you gain by using `\arg{\macro}` in `\multicolumn`, since this preamble is only used once??

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps analogous to @Martin's answer, you can box the cell contents using an `lrbox` environment, and then supply the boxed contents to your macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\begin{tabular}{c>{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}}c<{\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox\mybox}}c}
  One & Two & Three \\ \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) provides the means to insert content before `>{...}` and after `<{...}` a specific column. In this case, the `lrbox` environment start and end, as well as the resulting macro application for typesetting the cell content after boxing.

The restriction is mainly reliant on what can be boxed by the `lrbox` environment.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand*{\mycmda}[1]{\fbox{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mycmdb}[1]{\underline{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{Q[c,cmd=\mycmda]Q[c,cmd=\mycmdb]}
  Alpha & Gamma \\
  Beta  & Delta \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]