# Convert macro with one argument to switch

Tags: tables, macros

With the package `array`, I want to define a new column type for my tables with the command

```
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\switchon}{l}<{\switchoff}}
```

However, the command I’d like to use is not a switch but a plain, unary macro like `\emph` or `\textsc`, so I must define `\switchon` such that

```
{\switchon some text}
```

will be equivalent to

```
\macro{some text}
```

(if it must be, I could live with `\switchon some text \switchoff` but I think this is not necessary.)

Converting a switch to a macro (e.g. `\em` to `\emph`) is pretty simple but how would I do it the other way round?

**Edit**

It seems, I also have to fight this problem which does not seem to allow for an explicit `\switchoff` (because I need to support the X column type of `tabularx` and it does not seem to work well together with `newcolumntype`):

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\theswitch}m{#1}}
```

Where `\theswitch` must be some (sensible) combination of `\lowercase` and other font macros. `\lowercase` has no ‘switch’ version (I think) which makes things a bit complicated.

Comment: Was exactly is a *switch* to you? I only know the term from *if-switches*.

Comment: They use that name in the l2-tabu manual. (They also use the term global macro.) I guess it means a macro whose effect is valid until the next `\endgroup`.

Comment: Ok, I see. But this macros normally don't have a `\switchoff` version, which got me confused. Note that all font macros have "switch" versions as well.

Comment: Similar question: [How to apply a macro to each column of a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12599/2975)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `collcell` package to feed the cell content to a macro:

```
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcolumntype{U}{>{\collectcell\macro}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}
```

Then `\macro` will receive the cell content as only argument, i.e. `#1`.

---

If the macro should be simply `\emph` or `\textsc` you can use the "switch" versions directly. For `\emph` it would be `\em` and for `\textsc` it is `\scshape`. See e.g. http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rf10/pstex/latexcommands.htm for a table of such macros.

Comment: `collcell` is at the moment too new for our uses, unfortunately.

Comment: @Debilski: You can easily install it locally if your distribution doesn't provide it. See also my updated answer.

Comment: Bad thing is, I need to use `\lowercase` which has no ‘switch’ version.

Comment: @Debilski: with `collcell`, you can use any macro, and `\lowercase` as well.

Comment: @Debilski: If you don't want/can't use `collcell` you can use a macro like in TH. answer, but it wont work in the last column. See also the very similar question [How to apply a macro to each column of a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12599/2975) for alternatives like using `\halign` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Define a macro like

```
\def\switchon#1\switchoff{\foo{#1}}
```

perhaps.

Comment: I’m a bit ashamed of myself now, because I’ve already had this in the code but because a spurious `\textnormal` confused me, I did not notice it. Anyway, is it possible to have that without the explicit `\switchoff`?

Comment: This wont work in the last column of `array` because the `\switchoff` is "hidden" by the ``\\``.

Comment: @Debilski: You need the `\switchoff` to mark the end of the argument. But you can hide it like the collcell commands in a `\newcolumntype`: `\newcolumntype{V}{>{\switchon}l<{\switchoff}}`

Comment: @Martin: Good point!