# Tables header row's: how to ignore the column type?

Tags: tables, arrays, multicolumn

I have several column types defined using the `array` and `collcell` package. An example

```
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\collectcell\num}c<{\endcollectcell}}
```

This alleviates making tables a lot, and makes them more readable in the source file. Yet when I make a table with some header rows, I have to escape the column commands (the headers don't need to be inside the `\num`) using `\multicolumn`:

```
\begin{tabular}{NN}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Header 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Header 2}\\
    \hline
    1.234 & 2.345\\
    ....
\end{tabular}
```

is there a quicker way of doing this? Perhaps by redefining the column type mid-table, or having a command that will generate an escape row?

Comment: Perhaps [An improved `\rowstyle` that takes the cell contents as an argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32861/an-improved-rowstyle-that-takes-the-cell-contents-as-an-argument) will help; you would use conditionals to (de)activate a specific column operation.

Comment: You might exploit the table making features of the `siunitx` package, for numeric tables.

Comment: @egreg yes, yet I'm using different commands than `\num` alone and I would like an approach that works for the other commands too. Good tip though!

Comment: @Werner not a bad idea. Can't come up with a way that doesn't use save boxes though. (I can't put a save box inside, say, a `\num`, or even a `\textbf`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a switch that is enabled when the header is completed. This switch is checked to see if the column macros are to be applied.
When the header is completed, a call to `\EndTableHeader` needs to be made.

In the test below, the `N` column type applies the color red to each cell, and the result of:

```
\begin{tabular}{NN}
    \hline
    Header 1 & Header 1\EndTableHeader\\ 
    \hline 
    1.234 & 2.345\\
\end{tabular}
```

is that header column is not typeset in red:

[image]

### Notes:

- The solution here used the `\newtoggle` from the `etoolbox` package, as I find that syntax more readable. This can be adapted to the numerous other options for evaluating conditionals.
- I initialized the toggle when it is defined. Can probably get away with this, but I prefer to initialize variables when defined.
- Both the begin and end of the table are set to reset the toggle.  This to protect against any accident set/reset that may be applied outside of the table, and also allows for the case of header rows that may occur in the middle of a table.
- I am sure there unnecessary `%` at the end of the lines in the preamble, but I find it safer to just always add them in my preamble, rather than figure out if they are necessary

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{xcolor}% only needed for testing
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{inTableHeader}% Track if still in header of table
\toggletrue{inTableHeader}% Set initial value
\newcommand*{\StartTableHeader}{\global\toggletrue{inTableHeader}}%
\newcommand*{\EndTableHeader}{\global\togglefalse{inTableHeader}}%

% Redefine tabular to initialize \StartTableHeader at start and end
\let\OldTabular\tabular%
\let\OldEndTabular\endtabular%
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\StartTableHeader\OldTabular}{\OldEndTabular\StartTableHeader}%

% Define the column type:
\newcommand*{\myColorCell}[1]{\iftoggle{inTableHeader}{#1}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}%
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\collectcell\myColorCell}c<{\endcollectcell}}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{NN}
    \hline
    Header 1 & Header 1\EndTableHeader\\ 
    \hline 
    1.234 & 2.345\\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\noindent
Check again to make sure that settings are correct at start of table:

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{NN}
    \hline
    Header 1 & Header 1\EndTableHeader\\ 
    \hline 
    1.234 & 2.345\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```