# Applying a command to a whole column spawning "\ignorespaces"

Tags: tables, columns, minted, collcell

I am trying to apply a styling command to every cell of a table's column.

I define a new command invoking `minted`:

```
\newcommand{\ccode}[1]{\mintinline{c}{#1}}
```

And then, I apply this command in the header definition of a table:

```
\begin{tabular}{| >{\ccode}{l} | l |}
```

However, this results in some `\ignorespaces` randomly popping in the output file.

The following is an MWE and the corresponding output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand{\ccode}[1]{\mintinline{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| >{\ccode}{l} | l |}
    \hline
    int foo (int a, int b) & Foos a and b. \\ \hline
    int bar (int* a, int* b) & Bars a and b. \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output file]

Has anyone an idea about what is going on? Could it be related to the `minted` package?

I am running TeX Live 2013 on a Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks for your help.

---

**Related**

[How to execute command on every table column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59785/how-to-execute-command-on-every-table-column)

[How does the \newcolumntype command work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257128/how-does-the-newcolumntype-command-work)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I've been reading Q/A on this site for months though :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually, LaTeX adds `\ignorespaces` at the begin of a cell and `\unskip` at its end to automatically remove spaces at the begin and end of the cell contents.

The example loads package `collcell`, but does not use it. An example of its usage:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand{\ccode}[1]{\mintinline{C}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| >{\collectcell{\ccode}}l<{\endcollectcell} | l |}
    \hline
    int foo (int a, int b) & Foos a and b. \\ \hline
    int bar (int* a, int* b) & Bars a and b. \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

PS: I had to use `C` (uppercase) as language name to get the proper output.

## Analysis of the problem in the MWE of the question

First the MWE of the question with some modifications:

- Uppercase `C` as language name,
- Package `collcell` is not needed, but it loads package `array`, which implements `<` and `>` for the columns specification of the table.

Modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\ccode}[1]{\mintinline{C}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| >{\ccode}l | l |}
    \hline
    int foo (int a, int b) & Foos a and b. \\ \hline
    int bar (int* a, int* b) & Bars a and b. \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result of the MWE in the question]

`\ccode` is inserted in front of the cell contents. LaTeX automatically surrounds the cell contents with `\ignorespaces` and `\unskip` to remove spaces at the begin and end of a cell. Then the first cell becomes:

```
 \ccode \ignorespaces int foo (int a, int b)\unskip
```

Since curly argument braces are missing, the argument of `\ccode` is the first token `\ignorespaces`. The remaining part `int foo (int a, int )\unskip` is set as plain text.

`\unskip` could be used as end token for the argument and `\ignorespaces` can be absorbed by adding it to the parameter text of the definition of `\ccode`:

```
\def\ccode\ignorespaces#1\unskip{\mintinline{C}{#1}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{minted}

\def\ccode\ignorespaces#1\unskip{\mintinline{C}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| >{\ccode}l | l |}
    \hline
    int foo (int a, int b) & Foos a and b. \\ \hline
    int bar (int* a, int* b) & Bars a and b.\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Package `cellcoll` hides these internals, providing a more readable and maintainable interface.

Comment: Thank you very much, it perfectly works. I probably was confused by all the syntax of the table-related command. By the way, without the `collcell` package loaded, my MWE does not compile.

Comment: Actually, I still don't understand why my MWE was spawning these `\ignorespaces`.

Comment: @Rightleg You are grabbing the cell content verbatim, and `\ignorespaces` is always there as LaTeX itself inserts it at the start of the cell