# Why does siunitx typeset positive (+0) or negative zero (−0) without the sign?

Tags: tables, siunitx

When I write a TeX document and use `siunitx` to format positive and negative zero, the sign is not being typeset. This is even true with the `retain-explitcit-plus=true` option.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX TXS-program:lualatex = lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -output-directory="outdir" -aux-directory="auxdir" -shell-escape %.tex
% !TeX encoding = utf8
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ *{2}{S[retain-explicit-plus=true]}}
        {Number} & {Workaround} \\
        \hline
        -2 \\
        -1 \\
        -0 & {$-0$} \\
        +0 & {$+0$} \\
        +1 \\
        +2 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The workaround may cause misalignment under certain conditions.

Why does this happen? Is it intended? Is there a better solution than my workaround?

Comment: Zero is zero ...

Comment: "Zero is zero" – sometimes yes, sometimes no. Depends on the context and type of mathematics or engineering discipline.

Comment: @JosephWright there is `$\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}$`.

Comment: @genodeftest People tend to miss that `siunitx` is about _physical_ measurements. When you measure something as zero, you don't get a sign: you are making a judgement that the output of your measurement device is reading 'no signal' or similar.

Comment: On an implementation level, the first thing `siunitx` does is normalise the input: if the value is zero, the sign is dropped as it's got no meaning.

Comment: @JosephWright while that point is valid there is still a meaning to the sign of 0 e.g. in `\frac{1}{x}`.

Comment: @JosephWright: I understand `siunitx` to be about physical quantities, which may include theory. Anyway, so you are saying *this is out of scope*?

Comment: @JosephWright: Oh, you already answered that. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: @JosephWright: that seems inconsistent behaviour compared to what happens with rounding: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416283/

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I didn't say I get everything right :) (That's a question of ordering: rounding happens at a different step.)

Comment: @JosephWright It might make sense to keep the sign around, separately from the digits perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing @JosephWright's comment:

> On an implementation level, the first thing `siunitx` does is normalise the input: if the value is zero, the sign is dropped as it's got no meaning.

So the answer is: This behavior is by design and intended, because `siunitx` focuses on physical quantities, not on theoretical constructs or computer mathematics.