# tabular environment with random positions

Tags: tables, arrays, random-numbers

I would like to simulate a simple random cloud of letters using a custom tabular environment, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lcg}
\begin{document}

\reinitrand[first=12,last=20,counter=n]
\begin{tabular}[t]{*3{>{\rand\fontsize{\then}{\then}\selectfont}c}}
X & X & X \\
X & X & X \\
X & X & X \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

In addition, I also want to relocate "cells" in a similar way, but it is not possible because the syntax of the tabular environment supports declarations but not commands like `\put(,){}`

In other words, I would like to replace the \put command by any declaration inside the `tabular` preamble, in order to avoid this redundant syntax:

```
\newcount\x
\newcount\y  
\newcommand{\rndpos}[1]{
    \rand\x\then
    \rand\y\then
    \put(\x,\y){#1}
    }

\reinitrand[first=0,last=4,counter=n]
\begin{tabular}[t]{*3{>{\rand\fontsize{\numexpr 3*\then+10}{\then}\selectfont}c}}
\rndpos{X} & \rndpos{X} & \rndpos{X} \\
\rndpos{X} & \rndpos{X} & \rndpos{X} \\
\rndpos{X} & \rndpos{X} & \rndpos{X} \\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `collcell`. Also, see [How to execute command on every table column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59785/how-to-execute-command-on-every-table-column)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lcg}
%This friend makes the magic
\usepackage{collcell}
%Define a column type so the cell's content is passed as an argument to \rndpos. We can also put the random font size commands here
\newcommand{\rndsz}{%
\rand\fontsize{\numexpr 3*\then+10}{\then}\selectfont%
}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\rndsz\collectcell\rndpos}{c}<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcount\x
\newcount\y  
\newcommand{\rndpos}[1]{
    \rand\x\then
    \rand\y\then
    \put(\x,\y){#1}
}

\begin{document}
\reinitrand[first=0,last=4,counter=n]
\begin{tabular}[t]{*3{Z}}
    X & X & X \\
    X & X & X \\
    X & X & X \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

No need to define new environments, I think.

Comment: Why do you still use `\rndpos{X}` in the cell entry when you are using the `W` column type to apply `\rndpos`? Is this nested usage by design?

Comment: Sorry, I'm gonna edit that.

Comment: You should consider using a different letter than W as new column type. If you for some reasons load the array package, you will receive an error message, because W is one of the reserved column types.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to JairoAraujo’s fine answer (upvoted), here's a simpler implementation using `expl3`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,collcell}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\randomsizeandpos}{m}
 {
  \fontsize{\int_rand:nn{12}{20}}{0}\selectfont
  \put(\int_rand:nn{0}{4},\int_rand:nn{0}{4}){#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{>{\collectcell\randomsizeandpos}c<{\endcollectcell}} }
X & X & X \\
a & b & c \\
X & X & X \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]