# New environment question

Tags: environments

I am trying to create a new environment that works similar to the `{\bfseries }` command.

For example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{rotating}

\newenvironment{stext}
{\begin{sideways} \bfseries \raggedleft }
{\end{sideways}}

\begin{document}

\begin{stext}
This is an example environment.
\end{stext}

\end{document}
```

In the above example, I want to redefine the `stext` environment so that it works as follows:

```
{\stext This is an example environment.}
```

Here is the use case for this new environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{$l^c^r}
\rowstyle{\rotatebox{-90}}% <- I know, the usage is wrong. 
abc & abc & abc\\
b & b & b \\
c & c & c \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The aim here is to get the text in the first row sideways so that they don't occupy as much width. For the `\rowstyle` command to work properly, I need an environment which can be invoked like so:

```
{\rotatetext Rotated text}
```

Comment: Do you still want the contents to be rotated?

Comment: It's quite hard to understand why you'd want this. Can you give more motivation?

Comment: You could create a macro that wraps the text in the environment, e.g. \stext{Your text}; this is ALMOST like what you stated that you wanted...

Comment: @Werner, yes. It should do the same thing as the `stext` environment in the MWE.

Comment: @egreg For instance, I want the text in a row of a large table to be sideways so that it doesn't occupy as much width. I am using the solution from [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4811/make-first-row-of-table-all-bold) to apply a row style. However, the `\rowstyle` command here takes formatting commands in the form `{\formatting Text goes here}`. I cannot use a `begin{environment}`-`\end{environment}` construct here.

Comment: @Adi I don't think it's possible to do what you want with that `\rowstyle`. Consider `\rotatebox` instead of the `sideways` environment.

Comment: @egreg, I have updated my post with some details as to where and how I want to use it. I am afraid, I don't see how `\rotatebox` helps in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option using a slightly modified version of Herbert's answer to [An improved \rowstyle that takes the cell contents as an argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32861/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\newsavebox\TBox
\newif\ifrotate\rotatefalse
\newcolumntype{C}{%
  >{\begin{lrbox}{\TBox}} 
  c 
  <{\end{lrbox}\ifrotate\rotatebox{90}{\usebox\TBox}\else\usebox\TBox\fi}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*3C}
  \global\rotatetrue abc & abc & abc \\ \global\rotatefalse
  b & b & b \\
  c & c & c \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The idea behind this solution is to box the contents in `\TBox` and conditionally rotate it or not, based on `\ifrotate` - a boolean value set to true (`\rotatetrue`) or false (`\rotatefalse`).

It's usage should be clear from the example - place `\global\rotatetrue` in the first entry you want to rotate in that row, and `\global\rotatefalse` *after* the last entry. For convenience you could also define these as "switches" using

```
\newcommand{\rotateon}{\global\rotatetrue}% rotate switch ON
\newcommand{\rotateoff}{\global\rotatefalse}% rotate switch OFF
```

If you want different alignment for the respective columns, you can define an `L` and `R` column (say), similar to my `C`.

[`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) provides the `\rotatebox{<angle>}{<stuff>}` command to rotate `<stuff>` through an angle of `<angle>` degrees.

Comment: Quick follow-up question: How can I modify the code so as to allow text wrapping in the rotated text? I tried changing the column alignment from `c` to `p`, but that didn't work.

Comment: @Adi: You can place the contents in a `\parbox` of a specific width. For example, use `\parbox{2cm}{abc def ghi jkl}` in the above example for one of the header entries.