# Center a full selected row in a table

Tags: tables

I know I can use `\multicolumn{}{}{}` to center a single cell within a table with non-centered cells, but what is the best way to center all the cells in a given row?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{*6{l}}
    Name1 & Name2 & Name3 & Name4 & Name5 & Name6\\
    Type1 & Type2 & Type3 & Type4 & Type5 & Type6\\ % <- center this row
    Item1 & Item2 & Item3 & Item4 & Item5 & Item6\\
    Item7 & Item8 & Item9 & Item10 & Item11 & Item12\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [An improved `\rowstyle` that takes the cell contents as an argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32861/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to define a macro that accepts 6 parameters and applies a `\multicolumn` to each parameter:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\Mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}%
\newcommand*{\CenterRow}[6]{%
    \Mc{#1}&\Mc{#2}&\Mc{#3}&\Mc{#4}&\Mc{#5}&\Mc{#6}%
}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{*6{l}}
    Name1 & Name2 & Name3 & Name4 & Name5 & Name6\\
    \CenterRow{Type1}{Type2}{Type3}{Type4}{Type5}{Type6}\\ % <- center this row
    Item1 & Item2 & Item3 & Item4 & Item5 & Item6\\
    Item7 & Item8 & Item9 & Item10 & Item11 & Item12\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to keep the same syntax you could define a macro that accepts parameters delimited by `&`.

### Note:

- This yields identical results as above, however I am not sure what other issues this might cause.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\Mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}%

\newcommand*{\CenterRow}[6]{}% Make sure we not overwriting an existing macro
\def\CenterRow #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5 & #6\\{%
    \Mc{#1}&\Mc{#2}&\Mc{#3}&\Mc{#4}&\Mc{#5}&\Mc{#6} \\%
}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{*6{l}}
    Name1 & Name2 & Name3 & Name4 & Name5 & Name6\\
    \CenterRow Type1 & Type2 & Type3 & Type4 & Type5 & Type6 \\ % <- center this row
    Item1 & Item2 & Item3 & Item4 & Item5 & Item6\\
    Item7 & Item8 & Item9 & Item10 & Item11 & Item12\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second option is *very* risky, since you have to match the parameter text exactly. For example, dropping a space, or inserting a space between `#6` and ``\\`` would yield problems.

Comment: @Werner: Yep, that is why I added the "Note" -- This is the _first_ time I have defined a non-standard delimited macro so was surprised that it worked, at least for _this_ one case.

Answer (score 2):

For such tables, ConTeXt provides a much nicer interface. For example using natural tables, you can either use

```
\startsetups table:setup
  \setupTABLE[align=flushleft, frame=off]
  \setupTABLE[row][2][align=middle]
\stopsetups

\starttext
  \startTABLE[setups={table:setup}]
    \NC LongName1 \NC LongName2 \NC LongName3 \NC LongName4 \NC LongName5 \NC LongName6\NC\NR
    \NC Type1 \NC Type2 \NC Type3 \NC Type4 \NC Type5 \NC Type6\NC\NR % <- center this row
    \NC Item1 \NC Item2 \NC Item3 \NC Item4 \NC Item5 \NC Item6\NC\NR
    \NC Item7 \NC Item8 \NC Item9 \NC Item10 \NC Item11 \NC Item12\NC\NR
  \stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

or if you are not sure where row you want to center-align upfront, use

```
\starttext
\startTEXpage[offset=3mm]
  \bTABLE[align=flushleft, frame=off]
    \bTR 
       \bTD LongName1 \eTD \bTD LongName2 \eTD \bTD LongName3 \eTD \bTD LongName4 \eTD \bTD LongName5 \eTD \bTD LongName6\eTD
    \eTR
    \bTR[align=middle] 
       \bTD Type1 \eTD \bTD Type2 \eTD \bTD Type3 \eTD \bTD Type4 \eTD \bTD Type5 \eTD \bTD Type6\eTD
    \eTR 
    \bTR 
       \bTD Item1 \eTD \bTD Item2 \eTD \bTD Item3 \eTD \bTD Item4 \eTD \bTD Item5 \eTD \bTD Item6\eTD
     \eTR
    \bTR 
       \bTD Item7 \eTD \bTD Item8 \eTD \bTD Item9 \eTD \bTD Item10 \eTD \bTD Item11 \eTD \bTD Item12\eTD
    \eTR
  \eTABLE
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

both of these give

[image]