# How to change font color of a row in tabularx?

Tags: color, tabularx

I have a table and I want a font color of 5th and 6th row be red. What I'm doing right now is changing the color of each cell in these rows, is there any command which can change font color in a row, not just in one cell?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl,hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X|X| }
\hline
\textbf{Наименование} & \textbf{BBB} & \textbf{ААА} \\ \hline
Теплопостачання припливних систем & 83 044,00 грн. & 67 000 грн \\ \hline
Монтаж , пусканаладка & 64 000,00 грн. & 74885849 грн \\ \hline
\rowcolor{yellow}
ИТОГО: & 1089158,71 грн. & 100000 \\ \hline
\color{red} Отклонение от минимального предложения, грн & \color{red} 0,00 грн. & \color{red} 34000 \\ \hline
\color{red} Отклонение от минимального предложения, \% & \color{red} 0\% & \color{red} 10 \%  \\ \hline
Срок выполнения работ & 3-4 недели & 2 недели \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\vspace{1cm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [An improved `\rowstyle` that takes the cell contents as an argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32861/5764)

Comment: It is possible to hide but I would do what you have, and specify the colour in each cell, not however you should use `\textcolor{red}{..........}` not `\color` or you get the spurious extra space above the coloured rows as seen in your image.

Comment: @Werner, from answer in given link to desired change of text color in row is not so simply as maybe it seems on the first sight. An addendum to it with example how to change colors would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following builds on the technique described in [An improved `\rowstyle` that takes the cell contents as an argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32861/5764), capturing each cell using [`collcell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell):

[image]

Each cell `..` is set using `\textcolor{red}{..}` depending whether/not the switch `\ifrowcolour` has been set to `\rowcolourtrue` or `\rowcolourfalse`. Since these switches occur inside `tabular` cells (and therefore groups), they have to be set `\global`ly in order for the change to exist beyond the cell scope.

For visual appeal, I'd suggest using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for you table presentation(s).

Answer (score 2):

With new table package `tabularray`:

case 1: with horizontal and vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z}={solid, 0.5pt}, hline{3-Y}={dashed}, 
             vlines,
             colspec={*{3}{X[l]}},
             row{1} ={font=\bfseries}
             }
Наименование    & BBB               & ААА               \\
Теплопостачання припливних систем 
                & 83 044,00 грн.    & 67 000 грн        \\
Монтаж , пусканаладка 
                & 64 000,00 грн.    & 74 885 849 грн    \\
    \SetRow{yellow}
ИТОГО:          & 1089158,71 грн.   & 100 000           \\
    \SetRow{fg=red}
Отклонение от минимального предложения, грн & 0,00 грн. & 34000 \\
    \SetRow{fg=red}
Отклонение от минимального предложения, \% 
                & 0 \%              & 10 \%             \\
Срок выполнения работ 
                & 3-4 недели        & 2 недели          \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

case 2: horizontal lines at top, after column headers and at bottom, and without vertical lines. The table body is the same as before, changed are only table specifications:

```
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z}={solid, 0.5pt}, 
             colspec={*{3}{X[l]}},
             row{1} ={font=\bfseries}
             }
% table body, the same as before
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `{NiceTabular}`, you have a command `\RowStyle` to change the style of the end of the current row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{XXX}[hvlines]
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
Наименование & BBB & ААА \\ 
Теплопостачання припливних систем & 83 044,00 грн. & 67 000 грн \\ 
Монтаж , пусканаладка & 64 000,00 грн. & 74885849 грн \\ 
\RowStyle[rowcolor=yellow]{}
ИТОГО: & 1089158,71 грн. & 100000 \\ 
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2,color=red]{}
Отклонение от минимального предложения, грн & 0,00 грн. & 34000 \\ 
Отклонение от минимального предложения, \% & 0 \% & 10 \%  \\ 
Срок выполнения работ & 3-4 недели & 2 недели \\ 
\end{NiceTabularX}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]