# How to Enhance an Existing Math Environment

Tags: math-mode, environments, matrices

I'm taking the next step in my learning of LaTeX and starting to explore the possibility of creating custom environments; however, the resources I've consulted don't mention how to create an environment like the `bmatrix` environment that does not have a pre-defined number of arguments.

In particular, I'd like to define a variant of `bmatrix` (and similar) that allows me to colour the rows / columns.

Ideally, I'd like to figure out a way to define the environment so that I can:

- specify the colour of each row / column at the opening of the environment (or at the first element of the row / column). E.g. if `\ca`, `\cb` and `\cc` are macros for different colours, then something like `\begin{cbmatrix}{\ca \ca \cb}` would start a `bmatrix` environment where the entries in the first row will each be wrapped in `\ca`, similarly for the second row, and the entries of the third row would be wrapped in `cb`,

i.e. the desired output would be equivalent to:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
\ca{e1} & \ca{e2} & \ca{e3} & \ca{e4} \\
\ca{e5} & \ca{e6} & \ca{e7} & \ca{e8} \\
\cb{e9}& \cb{e10} & \cb{e11} & \cb{e12} \\
e13 & e14 & e15 & e16
\end{bmatrix}
```

- easily switch between applying the colour command to rows or columns (perhaps with a starred version of the environment)?

**I realize this is a very specific end-result, but I'm generally curious to know where to begin to be able to define this type of environment, where the number of inputs / arguments isn't predefined?**

Comment: bmatrix has no arguments so the number of arguments is defined, if you mean thenumber of array columns that is also defined (to 10) it is essentially `\begin{array}{*{10}{c}}`

Comment: There is a big difference between making settings at the column-level and the row-level. See, for example, [An improved `\rowstyle` that takes the cell contents as an argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32861/5764).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I meant the number of array columns (didn't know how to refer to the elements you place in the matrix). I didn't realize that `bmatrix` was limited to 10 (never had a larger array, I guess). So it just ignores unused columns?

Comment: @Werner thank you, I will have a close look at that; I suppose the quick take-away is that I will have to create two separate environments... Perhaps I can name them similarly, so toggling between them achieves a similar effect.

Comment: the 10 is a user-settable amsmath parameter, defaulting to 10, yes latex array and tabular always silently ignore unused columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very fragile mixture of `array`, `collcell`, and some internal macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\ca{\textcolor{red}}
\newcommand\cb{\textcolor{green}}
\newcommand\cc{\textcolor{blue}}

\newcounter{row}
\newcounter{col}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{triplecolorbmatrix}[1]
  {\setcounter{row}{1}%
   \@for\name:=#1\do{%
       \expandafter\def\csname rowcolor\number\value{row}\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\name}%
       \stepcounter{row}%
   }%
   \setcounter{row}{0}%
   \setcounter{col}{0}%
   \newcommand\colorrow{\csname rowcolor\number\value{row}\endcsname}%
   \let\@arraycrnormal\@arraycr
   \def\@arraycr{\setcounter{col}{0}\@arraycrnormal}%
   \left[\hspace{-\tabcolsep}\array{*{10}{>{\ifnum\value{col}=0\stepcounter{row}\fi\stepcounter{col}\collectcell\colorrow}c<{\endcollectcell}}}}
  {\endmatrix\right]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{triplecolorbmatrix}{\ca,\cb,\cc}
    e1  & e2  & e3  & e4  \\
    e5  & e6  & e7  & e8  \\
    e9  & e10 & e11 & e12 \\
    e13 & e14 & e15 & e16 \\
  \end{triplecolorbmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for this, I will study the solution & see if I can generalize away from it :) Did not expect such a quick & complete answer :) Why do you say it is a fragile mixture?