# Forcing case in table

Tags: tables, formatting, longtable

I was wondering if it was possible to force the case for a specific column in a table? Let's say the 3rd column of the following table to be lowercase.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

{\tiny
\begin{longtable}[1]{>{\itshape}l>{\itshape}l>{\itshape}l>{\itshape}lrr}

\caption{Summary of fish species sampled in both biogeographic provinces.} \\ 
  \hline

\textbf{Order} & \textbf{Family} & \textbf{Genus} & \textbf{Species} & \textbf{Mean abundance (catch per unit effort)} & \textbf{Mean length (cm)} \\ 
  \hline
Acipenseriformes & Acipenseridae & Acipenser & Brevirostrum & 3.67 & 59.90 \\ 
   &  &  & Oxyrinchus & 2.50 & 27.81 \\ 
   & Polyodontidae & Polyodon & Spathula & 1.50 & 14.25 \\ 
  Anguilliformes & Anguillidae & Anguilla & Rostrata & 1.38 & 43.64 \\ 
   & Congridae & Conger & Oceanicus & 1.00 & 20.10 \\ 
  Atheriniformes & Atherinopsidae & Membras & Martinica & 12.33 & 6.69 \\ 
   &  & Menidia & Menidia & 2.50 & 6.72 \\ 
  Aulopiformes & Synodontidae & Synodus & Foetens & 1.90 & 15.92 \\ 
  Batrachoidiformes & Batrachoididae & Opsanus & Beta & 2.58 & 15.30 \\ 
   &  &  & Pardus & 1.50 & 16.52 \\ 
   &  &  & Tau & 4.05 & 19.29 \\ 
   &  & Porichthys & Plectrodon & 1.20 & 28.51 \\ 
  Beloniformes & Belonidae & Strongylura & Marina & 6.00 & 20.15 \\ 
  Carcharhiniformes & Carcharhinidae & Carcharhinus & Isodon & 1.00 & 38.00 \\ 
   &  &  & Limbatus & 1.00 & 39.20 \\ 
   &  &  & Porosus & 1.00 & 50.50 \\ 
   & Sphyrnidae & Sphyrna & Tiburo & 1.00 & 37.47 \\ 
   & Triakidae & Mustelus & Canis & 4.67 & 53.95 \\ 
  Clupeiformes & Clupeidae & Alosa & Aestivalis & 3.62 & 7.95 \\ 
   &  &  & Pseudoharengus & 6.38 & 7.35 \\ 
   &  &  & Sapidissima & 7.33 & 10.43 \\ 
   &  & Brevoortia & Gunteri & 35.17 & 7.99 \\ 
   &  &  & Patronus & 20.81 & 8.79 \\ 
   &  &  & Smithi & 1.00 & 12.20 \\ 
   &  &  & Tyrannus & 5.69 & 13.19 \\ 
   &  & Clupea & Harengus & 21.11 & 10.08 \\ 
   &  & Dorosoma & Cepedianum & 14.26 & 16.91 \\ 
   &  &  & Petenense & 11.85 & 10.37 \\ 
   &  & Etrumeus & Teres & 1.00 & 20.00 \\ 
   &  & Harengula & Jaguana & 2.47 & 9.70 \\ 
   &  & Opisthonema & Oglinum & 2.22 & 8.46 \\ 
   &  & Sardinella & Aurita & 3.00 & 13.07 \\ 
   & Engraulidae & Anchoa & Hepsetus & 8.66 & 6.81 \\ 
   &  &  & Mitchilli & 14.00 & 5.12 \\ 
  Cypriniformes & Catostomidae & Carpiodes & Cyprinus & 12.00 & 38.84 \\ 
   &  & Catostomus & Commersoni & 2.00 & 22.07 \\ 
   &  & Moxostoma & Macrolepidotum & 1.00 & 37.40 \\ 
   & Cyprinidae & Carassius & Auratus & 2.50 & 26.49 \\ 
   &  & Cyprinus & Carpio & 2.83 & 57.31 \\ 
   &  & Notemigonus & Crysoleucas & 2.00 & 14.00 \\ 
   &  & Notropis & Atherinoides & 10.00 & 9.71 \\ 
   &  &  & Hudsonius & 2.67 & 8.17 \\ 
  Cyprinodontiformes & Fundulidae & Fundulus & Grandis & 14.00 & 9.95 \\ 
  Elopiformes & Elopidae & Elops & Saurus & 1.14 & 21.20 \\ 
  Gadiformes & Gadidae & Microgadus & Tomcod & 10.30 & 9.41 \\ 
   &  & Pollachius & Virens & 1.00 & 13.10 \\ 
   & Lotidae & Enchelyopus & Cimbrius & 1.50 & 21.48 \\ 
   & Merlucciidae & Merluccius & Bilinearis & 2.00 & 20.98 \\ 
   & Phycidae & Urophycis & Chuss & 3.67 & 24.75 \\ 
   &  &  & Regia & 4.62 & 21.65 \\ 
   &  &  & Tenuis & 3.86 & 21.56 \\ 
  Gasterosteiformes & Gasterosteidae & Gasterosteus & Aculeatus & 1.00 & 7.80 \\ 
  Lampriformes & Trachipteridae & Desmodema & Polystictum & 1.00 & 16.95 \\ 
  Lepisosteiformes & Lepisosteidae & Atractosteus & Spatula & 1.00 & 48.00 \\ 
   &  & Lepisosteus & Oculatus & 1.00 & 47.00 \\ 
   &  &  & Osseus & 4.00 & 91.18 \\ 
  Lophiiformes & Ogcocephalidae & Ogcocephalus & Radiatus & 1.00 & 19.70 \\ 
  Mugiliformes & Mugilidae & Mugil & Cephalus & 2.89 & 17.53 \\ 
   &  &  & Curema & 1.57 & 12.21 \\ 
  Ophidiiformes & Ophidiidae & Ophidion & Marginatum & 1.50 & 16.85 \\ 
  Osmeriformes & Osmeridae & Osmerus & Mordax & 1.00 & 12.15 \\ 
  Perciformes & Carangidae & Carangoides & Ruber & 6.00 & 6.48 \\ 
   &  & Caranx & Crysos & 2.00 & 15.07 \\ 
   &  &  & Hippos & 3.09 & 8.92 \\ 
   &  &  & Latus & 2.00 & 8.91 \\ 
   &  & Chloroscombrus & Chrysurus & 25.50 & 7.31 \\ 
   &  & Decapterus & Punctatus & 7.00 & 13.21 \\ 
   &  & Hemicaranx & Amblyrhynchus & 2.67 & 12.01 \\ 
   &  & Selar & Crumenophthalmus & 7.00 & 9.40 \\ 
   &  & Selene & Setapinnis & 1.62 & 6.00 \\ 
   &  &  & Vomer & 2.14 & 5.60 \\ 
   &  & Trachinotus & Carolinus & 2.00 & 9.89 \\ 
   &  &  & Falcatus & 4.50 & 6.98 \\ 
   & Centrarchidae & Lepomis & Gibbosus & 8.14 & 11.13 \\ 
   &  &  & Macrochirus & 4.86 & 14.94 \\ 
   &  &  & Microlophus & 3.00 & 10.13 \\ 
   &  & Micropterus & Salmoides & 1.00 & 10.50 \\ 
   &  & Pomoxis & Annularis & 1.40 & 15.12 \\ 
   & Centropomidae & Centropomus & Undecimalis & 1.00 & 24.00 \\ 
   & Chaetodontidae & Chaetodon & Ocellatus & 2.00 & 4.85 \\ 
   & Ephippidae & Chaetodipterus & Faber & 3.13 & 7.47 \\ 
   & Gerreidae & Eucinostomus & Argenteus & 3.20 & 7.03 \\ 
   &  &  & Gula & 1.40 & 9.18 \\ 
   &  &  & Lefroyi & 6.50 & 7.64 \\ 
   & Gobiidae & Gobioides & Broussonneti & 1.00 & 19.60 \\ 
   &  & Gobiosoma & Bosc & 3.00 & 3.63 \\ 
   & Haemulidae & Haemulon & Plumieri & 9.50 & 8.96 \\ 
   &  & Orthopristis & Chrysoptera & 7.60 & 12.00 \\ 
   & Labridae & Halichoeres & Caudalis & 1.00 & 11.50 \\ 
   &  & Lachnolaimus & Maximus & 5.00 & 6.80 \\ 
   &  & Tautoga & Onitis & 10.60 & 17.06 \\ 
   &  & Tautogolabrus & Adspersus & 4.11 & 10.22 \\ 
   & Lutjanidae & Lutjanus & Griseus & 2.00 & 10.30 \\ 
   &  &  & Synagris & 2.67 & 8.16 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

Regards,
Phil

Comment: Hi Phil, welcome to the site. Could you post the contents of a small
compilable `.tex` file, starting with 
`\documentclass` and ending with 
`\end{document}`? Then I can paste it 
into my editor, reproduce your situation 
on my machine, and start thinking about 
a solution.

Comment: You can build on this answer by Martin Scharrer: (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12618/25356). Take the first of the two code snippets he gives, and change the `\fbox` to `\lowercase`.

Answer (score 3):

The [`collcell` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) is designed specifically to manage this requirement. From the [`collcell` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/collcell/collcell.pdf):

> This package provides macros which collect the cell content of a `tabular` and provide it to a macro as argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{longtable,array}
\usepackage{collcell}% http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell

\begin{document}

{\tiny
\begin{longtable}[1]{>{\itshape}l>{\itshape}l>{\itshape\collectcell\MakeLowercase}l<{\endcollectcell}>{\itshape}lrr}

\caption{Summary of fish species sampled in both biogeographic provinces.} \\ 
  \hline

\textbf{Order} & \textbf{Family} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{\textbf{Genus}}} & \textbf{Species} & \textbf{Mean abundance (catch per unit effort)} & \textbf{Mean length (cm)} \\ 
  \hline
Acipenseriformes & Acipenseridae & Acipenser & Brevirostrum & 3.67 & 59.90 \\ 
   &  &  & Oxyrinchus & 2.50 & 27.81 \\ 
   & Polyodontidae & Polyodon & Spathula & 1.50 & 14.25 \\ 
  Anguilliformes & Anguillidae & Anguilla & Rostrata & 1.38 & 43.64 \\ 
   & Congridae & Conger & Oceanicus & 1.00 & 20.10 \\ 
  Atheriniformes & Atherinopsidae & Membras & Martinica & 12.33 & 6.69 \\ 
   &  & Menidia & Menidia & 2.50 & 6.72 \\ 
  Aulopiformes & Synodontidae & Synodus & Foetens & 1.90 & 15.92 \\ 
  Batrachoidiformes & Batrachoididae & Opsanus & Beta & 2.58 & 15.30 \\ 
   &  &  & Pardus & 1.50 & 16.52 \\ 
   &  &  & Tau & 4.05 & 19.29 \\ 
   &  & Porichthys & Plectrodon & 1.20 & 28.51 \\ 
  Beloniformes & Belonidae & Strongylura & Marina & 6.00 & 20.15 \\ 
  Carcharhiniformes & Carcharhinidae & Carcharhinus & Isodon & 1.00 & 38.00 \\ 
   &  &  & Limbatus & 1.00 & 39.20 \\ 
   &  &  & Porosus & 1.00 & 50.50 \\ 
   & Sphyrnidae & Sphyrna & Tiburo & 1.00 & 37.47 \\ 
   & Triakidae & Mustelus & Canis & 4.67 & 53.95 \\ 
  Clupeiformes & Clupeidae & Alosa & Aestivalis & 3.62 & 7.95 \\ 
   &  &  & Pseudoharengus & 6.38 & 7.35 \\ 
   &  &  & Sapidissima & 7.33 & 10.43 \\ 
   &  & Brevoortia & Gunteri & 35.17 & 7.99 \\ 
   &  &  & Patronus & 20.81 & 8.79 \\ 
   &  &  & Smithi & 1.00 & 12.20 \\ 
   &  &  & Tyrannus & 5.69 & 13.19 \\ 
   &  & Clupea & Harengus & 21.11 & 10.08 \\ 
   &  & Dorosoma & Cepedianum & 14.26 & 16.91 \\ 
   &  &  & Petenense & 11.85 & 10.37 \\ 
   &  & Etrumeus & Teres & 1.00 & 20.00 \\ 
   &  & Harengula & Jaguana & 2.47 & 9.70 \\ 
   &  & Opisthonema & Oglinum & 2.22 & 8.46 \\ 
   &  & Sardinella & Aurita & 3.00 & 13.07 \\ 
   & Engraulidae & Anchoa & Hepsetus & 8.66 & 6.81 \\ 
   &  &  & Mitchilli & 14.00 & 5.12 \\ 
  Cypriniformes & Catostomidae & Carpiodes & Cyprinus & 12.00 & 38.84 \\ 
   &  & Catostomus & Commersoni & 2.00 & 22.07 \\ 
   &  & Moxostoma & Macrolepidotum & 1.00 & 37.40 \\ 
   & Cyprinidae & Carassius & Auratus & 2.50 & 26.49 \\ 
   &  & Cyprinus & Carpio & 2.83 & 57.31 \\ 
   &  & Notemigonus & Crysoleucas & 2.00 & 14.00 \\ 
   &  & Notropis & Atherinoides & 10.00 & 9.71 \\ 
   &  &  & Hudsonius & 2.67 & 8.17 \\ 
  Cyprinodontiformes & Fundulidae & Fundulus & Grandis & 14.00 & 9.95 \\ 
  Elopiformes & Elopidae & Elops & Saurus & 1.14 & 21.20 \\ 
  Gadiformes & Gadidae & Microgadus & Tomcod & 10.30 & 9.41 \\ 
   &  & Pollachius & Virens & 1.00 & 13.10 \\ 
   & Lotidae & Enchelyopus & Cimbrius & 1.50 & 21.48 \\ 
   & Merlucciidae & Merluccius & Bilinearis & 2.00 & 20.98 \\ 
   & Phycidae & Urophycis & Chuss & 3.67 & 24.75 \\ 
   &  &  & Regia & 4.62 & 21.65 \\ 
   &  &  & Tenuis & 3.86 & 21.56 \\ 
  Gasterosteiformes & Gasterosteidae & Gasterosteus & Aculeatus & 1.00 & 7.80 \\ 
  Lampriformes & Trachipteridae & Desmodema & Polystictum & 1.00 & 16.95 \\ 
  Lepisosteiformes & Lepisosteidae & Atractosteus & Spatula & 1.00 & 48.00 \\ 
   &  & Lepisosteus & Oculatus & 1.00 & 47.00 \\ 
   &  &  & Osseus & 4.00 & 91.18 \\ 
  Lophiiformes & Ogcocephalidae & Ogcocephalus & Radiatus & 1.00 & 19.70 \\ 
  Mugiliformes & Mugilidae & Mugil & Cephalus & 2.89 & 17.53 \\ 
   &  &  & Curema & 1.57 & 12.21 \\ 
  Ophidiiformes & Ophidiidae & Ophidion & Marginatum & 1.50 & 16.85 \\ 
  Osmeriformes & Osmeridae & Osmerus & Mordax & 1.00 & 12.15 \\ 
  Perciformes & Carangidae & Carangoides & Ruber & 6.00 & 6.48 \\ 
   &  & Caranx & Crysos & 2.00 & 15.07 \\ 
   &  &  & Hippos & 3.09 & 8.92 \\ 
   &  &  & Latus & 2.00 & 8.91 \\ 
   &  & Chloroscombrus & Chrysurus & 25.50 & 7.31 \\ 
   &  & Decapterus & Punctatus & 7.00 & 13.21 \\ 
   &  & Hemicaranx & Amblyrhynchus & 2.67 & 12.01 \\ 
   &  & Selar & Crumenophthalmus & 7.00 & 9.40 \\ 
   &  & Selene & Setapinnis & 1.62 & 6.00 \\ 
   &  &  & Vomer & 2.14 & 5.60 \\ 
   &  & Trachinotus & Carolinus & 2.00 & 9.89 \\ 
   &  &  & Falcatus & 4.50 & 6.98 \\ 
   & Centrarchidae & Lepomis & Gibbosus & 8.14 & 11.13 \\ 
   &  &  & Macrochirus & 4.86 & 14.94 \\ 
   &  &  & Microlophus & 3.00 & 10.13 \\ 
   &  & Micropterus & Salmoides & 1.00 & 10.50 \\ 
   &  & Pomoxis & Annularis & 1.40 & 15.12 \\ 
   & Centropomidae & Centropomus & Undecimalis & 1.00 & 24.00 \\ 
   & Chaetodontidae & Chaetodon & Ocellatus & 2.00 & 4.85 \\ 
   & Ephippidae & Chaetodipterus & Faber & 3.13 & 7.47 \\ 
   & Gerreidae & Eucinostomus & Argenteus & 3.20 & 7.03 \\ 
   &  &  & Gula & 1.40 & 9.18 \\ 
   &  &  & Lefroyi & 6.50 & 7.64 \\ 
   & Gobiidae & Gobioides & Broussonneti & 1.00 & 19.60 \\ 
   &  & Gobiosoma & Bosc & 3.00 & 3.63 \\ 
   & Haemulidae & Haemulon & Plumieri & 9.50 & 8.96 \\ 
   &  & Orthopristis & Chrysoptera & 7.60 & 12.00 \\ 
   & Labridae & Halichoeres & Caudalis & 1.00 & 11.50 \\ 
   &  & Lachnolaimus & Maximus & 5.00 & 6.80 \\ 
   &  & Tautoga & Onitis & 10.60 & 17.06 \\ 
   &  & Tautogolabrus & Adspersus & 4.11 & 10.22 \\ 
   & Lutjanidae & Lutjanus & Griseus & 2.00 & 10.30 \\ 
   &  &  & Synagris & 2.67 & 8.16 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

In order to override the impact of `\collectcell`...`\endcollectcell`, you use `\multicolumn{1}{.}{..}`.

Comment: @user33438: Consider voting on the answers you receive, and finally [accepting the one that helped you most](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ).

Answer (score 0):

I changed four lines.  First, I added these two:

```
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\def\mklower#1{\caselower}
```

and then I modified this one:

```
\begin{longtable}[1]{>{\itshape}l>{\itshape}l>{\itshape\mklower}l>{\itshape}lrr}
```

and this one:

```
\textbf{Order} & \textbf{Family} & \ \unskip\textbf{Genus} & \textbf...
```

Note that this will only make the first character lowercase, but, for this table, that works fine.

```
        \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{amsfonts}
        \usepackage{amssymb}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{longtable}
        \usepackage{array}
        \usepackage{stringstrings}
        \def\mklower#1{\caselower}

        \begin{document}

        {\tiny
        \begin{longtable}[1]{>{\itshape}l>{\itshape}l>{\itshape\mklower}l>{\itshape}lrr}

        \caption{Summary of fish species sampled in both biogeographic provinces.} \\ 
          \hline

        \textbf{Order} & \textbf{Family} & \ \unskip\textbf{Genus} & \textbf{Species} & \textbf{Mean abundance (catch per unit effort)} & \textbf{Mean length (cm)} \\ 
          \hline
        Acipenseriformes & Acipenseridae & Acipenser & Brevirostrum & 3.67 & 59.90 \\ 
           &  &  & Oxyrinchus & 2.50 & 27.81 \\ 
           & Polyodontidae & Polyodon & Spathula & 1.50 & 14.25 \\ 
          Anguilliformes & Anguillidae & Anguilla & Rostrata & 1.38 & 43.64 \\ 
           & Congridae & Conger & Oceanicus & 1.00 & 20.10 \\ 
          Atheriniformes & Atherinopsidae & Membras & Martinica & 12.33 & 6.69 \\ 
           &  & Menidia & Menidia & 2.50 & 6.72 \\ 
          Aulopiformes & Synodontidae & Synodus & Foetens & 1.90 & 15.92 \\ 
          Batrachoidiformes & Batrachoididae & Opsanus & Beta & 2.58 & 15.30 \\ 
           &  &  & Pardus & 1.50 & 16.52 \\ 
           &  &  & Tau & 4.05 & 19.29 \\ 
           &  & Porichthys & Plectrodon & 1.20 & 28.51 \\ 
          Beloniformes & Belonidae & Strongylura & Marina & 6.00 & 20.15 \\ 
          Carcharhiniformes & Carcharhinidae & Carcharhinus & Isodon & 1.00 & 38.00 \\ 
           &  &  & Limbatus & 1.00 & 39.20 \\ 
           &  &  & Porosus & 1.00 & 50.50 \\ 
           & Sphyrnidae & Sphyrna & Tiburo & 1.00 & 37.47 \\ 
           & Triakidae & Mustelus & Canis & 4.67 & 53.95 \\ 
          Clupeiformes & Clupeidae & Alosa & Aestivalis & 3.62 & 7.95 \\ 
           &  &  & Pseudoharengus & 6.38 & 7.35 \\ 
           &  &  & Sapidissima & 7.33 & 10.43 \\ 
           &  & Brevoortia & Gunteri & 35.17 & 7.99 \\ 
           &  &  & Patronus & 20.81 & 8.79 \\ 
           &  &  & Smithi & 1.00 & 12.20 \\ 
           &  &  & Tyrannus & 5.69 & 13.19 \\ 
           &  & Clupea & Harengus & 21.11 & 10.08 \\ 
           &  & Dorosoma & Cepedianum & 14.26 & 16.91 \\ 
           &  &  & Petenense & 11.85 & 10.37 \\ 
           &  & Etrumeus & Teres & 1.00 & 20.00 \\ 
           &  & Harengula & Jaguana & 2.47 & 9.70 \\ 
           &  & Opisthonema & Oglinum & 2.22 & 8.46 \\ 
           &  & Sardinella & Aurita & 3.00 & 13.07 \\ 
           & Engraulidae & Anchoa & Hepsetus & 8.66 & 6.81 \\ 
           &  &  & Mitchilli & 14.00 & 5.12 \\ 
          Cypriniformes & Catostomidae & Carpiodes & Cyprinus & 12.00 & 38.84 \\ 
           &  & Catostomus & Commersoni & 2.00 & 22.07 \\ 
           &  & Moxostoma & Macrolepidotum & 1.00 & 37.40 \\ 
           & Cyprinidae & Carassius & Auratus & 2.50 & 26.49 \\ 
           &  & Cyprinus & Carpio & 2.83 & 57.31 \\ 
           &  & Notemigonus & Crysoleucas & 2.00 & 14.00 \\ 
           &  & Notropis & Atherinoides & 10.00 & 9.71 \\ 
           &  &  & Hudsonius & 2.67 & 8.17 \\ 
          Cyprinodontiformes & Fundulidae & Fundulus & Grandis & 14.00 & 9.95 \\ 
          Elopiformes & Elopidae & Elops & Saurus & 1.14 & 21.20 \\ 
          Gadiformes & Gadidae & Microgadus & Tomcod & 10.30 & 9.41 \\ 
           &  & Pollachius & Virens & 1.00 & 13.10 \\ 
           & Lotidae & Enchelyopus & Cimbrius & 1.50 & 21.48 \\ 
           & Merlucciidae & Merluccius & Bilinearis & 2.00 & 20.98 \\ 
           & Phycidae & Urophycis & Chuss & 3.67 & 24.75 \\ 
           &  &  & Regia & 4.62 & 21.65 \\ 
           &  &  & Tenuis & 3.86 & 21.56 \\ 
          Gasterosteiformes & Gasterosteidae & Gasterosteus & Aculeatus & 1.00 & 7.80 \\ 
          Lampriformes & Trachipteridae & Desmodema & Polystictum & 1.00 & 16.95 \\ 
          Lepisosteiformes & Lepisosteidae & Atractosteus & Spatula & 1.00 & 48.00 \\ 
           &  & Lepisosteus & Oculatus & 1.00 & 47.00 \\ 
           &  &  & Osseus & 4.00 & 91.18 \\ 
          Lophiiformes & Ogcocephalidae & Ogcocephalus & Radiatus & 1.00 & 19.70 \\ 
          Mugiliformes & Mugilidae & Mugil & Cephalus & 2.89 & 17.53 \\ 
           &  &  & Curema & 1.57 & 12.21 \\ 
          Ophidiiformes & Ophidiidae & Ophidion & Marginatum & 1.50 & 16.85 \\ 
          Osmeriformes & Osmeridae & Osmerus & Mordax & 1.00 & 12.15 \\ 
          Perciformes & Carangidae & Carangoides & Ruber & 6.00 & 6.48 \\ 
           &  & Caranx & Crysos & 2.00 & 15.07 \\ 
           &  &  & Hippos & 3.09 & 8.92 \\ 
           &  &  & Latus & 2.00 & 8.91 \\ 
           &  & Chloroscombrus & Chrysurus & 25.50 & 7.31 \\ 
           &  & Decapterus & Punctatus & 7.00 & 13.21 \\ 
           &  & Hemicaranx & Amblyrhynchus & 2.67 & 12.01 \\ 
           &  & Selar & Crumenophthalmus & 7.00 & 9.40 \\ 
           &  & Selene & Setapinnis & 1.62 & 6.00 \\ 
           &  &  & Vomer & 2.14 & 5.60 \\ 
           &  & Trachinotus & Carolinus & 2.00 & 9.89 \\ 
           &  &  & Falcatus & 4.50 & 6.98 \\ 
           & Centrarchidae & Lepomis & Gibbosus & 8.14 & 11.13 \\ 
           &  &  & Macrochirus & 4.86 & 14.94 \\ 
           &  &  & Microlophus & 3.00 & 10.13 \\ 
           &  & Micropterus & Salmoides & 1.00 & 10.50 \\ 
           &  & Pomoxis & Annularis & 1.40 & 15.12 \\ 
           & Centropomidae & Centropomus & Undecimalis & 1.00 & 24.00 \\ 
           & Chaetodontidae & Chaetodon & Ocellatus & 2.00 & 4.85 \\ 
           & Ephippidae & Chaetodipterus & Faber & 3.13 & 7.47 \\ 
           & Gerreidae & Eucinostomus & Argenteus & 3.20 & 7.03 \\ 
           &  &  & Gula & 1.40 & 9.18 \\ 
           &  &  & Lefroyi & 6.50 & 7.64 \\ 
           & Gobiidae & Gobioides & Broussonneti & 1.00 & 19.60 \\ 
           &  & Gobiosoma & Bosc & 3.00 & 3.63 \\ 
           & Haemulidae & Haemulon & Plumieri & 9.50 & 8.96 \\ 
           &  & Orthopristis & Chrysoptera & 7.60 & 12.00 \\ 
           & Labridae & Halichoeres & Caudalis & 1.00 & 11.50 \\ 
           &  & Lachnolaimus & Maximus & 5.00 & 6.80 \\ 
           &  & Tautoga & Onitis & 10.60 & 17.06 \\ 
           &  & Tautogolabrus & Adspersus & 4.11 & 10.22 \\ 
           & Lutjanidae & Lutjanus & Griseus & 2.00 & 10.30 \\ 
           &  &  & Synagris & 2.67 & 8.16 \\ 
           \hline
        \hline
        \end{longtable}
        }

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for your help and clear explanations.

Comment: @user33438  You're welcome.  Note the edit I did to make sure that the word "Genus" didn't have an extra space on the left end.