# Using array columns as arguments of a macro

Tags: arrows, arrays

I am creating a table using `array`, and I want one of my columns to be used as the argument of `xrightarrow` as shown below. To make the code cleaner, I want to avoid having to write `xrightarrow` for each row of the table. I tried using the functionality of the `array` package to make the second column the argument of `xrightarrow` (my feeble attempts are commented out below). Is there any way to make this work, or do I need to repeat the `xrightarrow` for each row of the table?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{array}{l@{\qquad}c@{\qquad}l}
        Y = \alpha X^{\beta}
        & \xrightarrow{X' = \log(X) , Y' = \log(Y)}
        & Y' = \log(\alpha) + \beta X' \\
        Y = \alpha \exp(\beta X)
        & \xrightarrow{Y' = \log(Y)}
        & Y' = \log(\alpha) + \beta X
    \end{array}
\]

%\[
%   \begin{array}{l@{\qquad}>{\xrightarrow}c@{\qquad}l}
%       Y = \alpha X^{\beta}
%       & X' = \log(X) , Y' = \log(Y)
%       & Y' = \log(\alpha) + \beta X' \\
%       Y = \alpha \exp(\beta X)
%       & Y' = \log(Y)
%       & Y' = \log(\alpha) + \beta X
%   \end{array}
%\]
%
%\[
%   \begin{array}{l@{\qquad}>{\xrightarrow{}c<{}}@{\qquad}l}
%       Y = \alpha X^{\beta}
%       & X' = \log(X) , Y' = \log(Y)
%       & Y' = \log(\alpha) + \beta X' \\
%       Y = \alpha \exp(\beta X)
%       & Y' = \log(Y)
%       & Y' = \log(\alpha) + \beta X
%   \end{array}
%\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: See (possible duplicate): [How to apply a macro to each column of a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12599/5764). The easiest way is to use [`collcell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) to collect the contents of a cell and pass it to a macro.