# table with a column of verbatim

Tags: verbatim

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    %\begin{tabular}{ l l }
    \begin{tabular}{ >{\verb=}l<{=} l }
    %   Chap2.nb & notebook \\
        PI_all_data_BBB_M15X.pdf     & Results for \verb=BBB= model with profile plots \\
        PI_all_data_BetaBin_M15X.pdf & Results for \verb=BetaBin= model with profile plots \\
        PI_all_data_BinLNB_M15X.pdf  & Results for \verb=BinLNB= model with profile plots \\
        PI_all_data_Bin_M15X.pdf     & Results for \verb=Bin= model with profile plots \\
        PI_all_data_LogGamma_M15X.pdf& Results for \verb=LogGamma= model with profile plots \\
        PI_all_data_TwoBin_M15X.pdf  & Results for \verb=TwoBin= model with profile plots \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

I want the first column to be verbatim for every row. Currerntly, the result is very weird, it seems that it goes into the 2nd column as well.

How would I change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`collcell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) to collect the cell contents, and then parse it `\detokenize`d:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,collcell}
\newcommand{\myverb}[1]{\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ >{\collectcell\myverb}l<{\endcollectcell} l }
  PI_all_data_BBB_M15X.pdf     & Results for \verb=BBB= model with profile plots \\
  PI_all_data_BetaBin_M15X.pdf & Results for \verb=BetaBin= model with profile plots \\
  PI_all_data_BinLNB_M15X.pdf  & Results for \verb=BinLNB= model with profile plots \\
  PI_all_data_Bin_M15X.pdf     & Results for \verb=Bin= model with profile plots \\
  PI_all_data_LogGamma_M15X.pdf& Results for \verb=LogGamma= model with profile plots \\
  PI_all_data_TwoBin_M15X.pdf  & Results for \verb=TwoBin= model with profile plots
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

As reference, see [Underscores in words (text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48632/5764) and [How to apply a macro to each column of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12599/5764).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I knew how to use underscores, but I was not sure how to put a column into verb format.

Answer (score 4):

For printing file names you don't need `\verb`, just that the underscore becomes printable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ >{\ttfamily\catcode`_=12 }l l }
% Chap2.nb & notebook \\
PI_all_data_BBB_M15X.pdf      & Results for \texttt{BBB} model with profile plots \\
PI_all_data_BetaBin_M15X.pdf  & Results for \texttt{BetaBin} model with profile plots \\
PI_all_data_BinLNB_M15X.pdf   & Results for \texttt{BinLNB} model with profile plots \\
PI_all_data_Bin_M15X.pdf      & Results for \texttt{Bin} model with profile plots \\
PI_all_data_LogGamma_M15X.pdf & Results for \texttt{LogGamma} model with profile plots \\
PI_all_data_TwoBin_M15X.pdf   & Results for \texttt{TwoBin} model with profile plots \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does that `=12` do?

Comment: @ChenStatsYu ``\catcode`_=12`` is the secret trick that makes the underscore printable, don't tell anybody. `;-)` It will do it only for the cells in that column.