# How do I use < and > column specifiers?

Tags: tables

I can't quite figure it out. I'd like to be able to process the entries in a table, but > and < aren't (quite) acting as I expect them to. Here's a repro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\foo}c<{\bar}}
\def\foo#1\bar{foo #1 bar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ZZZZ}
A & B & C & D \\
E & F & G & H
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

When I run this through `xelatex` I get the following output:

```
$ xelatex repro
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/MacPorts 2017_0) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./repro.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 5 language(s) loaded.
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/array.sty) (./repro.aux)
! Misplaced \cr.
\reserved@c ->\ifnum 0=`{}\fi \cr 

l.8 E &
        F & G & H
?
```

Oddly, it works as I expect if I use `{ZZcc}` as the preamble, but that must surely be only lucky. How do I use > and < column specifiers to process table entries?

Comment: Related [How to apply a macro to each column of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12599/2693).

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks, `collcell` (mentioned in the answers to that question) looks like it will help!

Comment: Yes, `collcell` is a great package for this kind of thing. It's not needed for simple things, but for more complicated processing of the cell it makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last column is not so easy to catch, because it is not ended by `&`. Then `\foo` gets all the stuff up to the next `&` including `\\`.

A workaround is to add a dummy last column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\foo}c<{\bar}}
\def\foo#1\bar{foo #1 bar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ZZZZ@{}c}
A & B & C & D &\\
E & F & G & H &
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, that explains it! Seems like something that should be mentioned in Mittelbach and Carlisle's "A new implementation of LaTeX's tabular and array environment" but at least now I understand the problem.